# iOS strange "unable to activate constraint with anchors" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The ios app I am currently developing starts off on a login screen which then presents the next view controller via a login button. Upon moving on to the next VC I get the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', 
reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors 
<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000d0af40 "UIStackView:0x7fe87df14160.top"> and
<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600000d0ad40 "UILayoutGuide:0x600002102300'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom"> 
because they have no common ancestor.  
Does the constraint or its anchors reference items
in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'
```

Here is the relevant VC code for the contoller being showed:

```
let promptLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "Enter Your Location`s \nAddress"
    label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.width
    label.textAlignment = .center
    
    return label
}()

let streetAddressField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()

    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.placeholder = "street address" 
    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    textField.textAlignment = .left

    return textField
}()

let cityField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()

    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.placeholder = "city"
    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    textField.textAlignment = .left

    return textField
}()

let stateField: UITextField = {
    let textField = UITextField()

    textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textField.placeholder = "state"
    textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    textField.textAlignment = .left

    return textField
}()

let saveButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Add Location", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return button
}()

var currentUser: User?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    let views: [UIView] = [streetAddressField, cityField, stateField]
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)
    
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 17
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(promptLabel)
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    view.addSubview(saveButton)
            
    promptLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    promptLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    
    promptLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: promptLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    
    stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    
    saveButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    saveButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addLocationTouchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

What is also odd is that this error does not show up for a while. When testing on different iphone simulators the error takes quite a few runs to show up. Also the error shows up at the `@main` line in `AppDelegate.swift`.

I am aware that there are multiple duplicates to this question. However all of them simply did not add their subviews to the superview which I have done here.

UPDATE: I had updated to xcode 13 and stopped seeing this error. Unfortunately it has reared its ugly head yet again on both the simulator and my personal iphone.

UPDATE2: After setting numerous breakpoints It would seem this error appears even before `viewWillAppear()` is called. Going back to my previous VC right after `self.navigationController.pushViewController()` is called is when we see the error. (`self` here referring to the previous VC of course)

Comment: I have several questions, but the first is: Is there some code you're not showing us? The problematic constraint described in the error message isn't _any_ of the constraints shown in your code. It is a constraint from the stack view top to the safe area bottom, which sounds really weird.

Comment: Also, what happens if you kill the line `let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: views)`? What if you say `let stackView = UIStackView()` or similar, and don't set the arranged subviews until _after_ the stack view has been added as a subview to the interface? Does that solve it? If not, we might have to take more drastic measures, like postponing the constraint creation until the `updateConstraints` call.

Comment: @matt very strange indeed. I dont even think I have any constraints of this nature in ANY of my view controllers, so I am confused in the same sense you are. Nonetheless I am going to try some of these suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that you report having to try several times to expose the issue makes me wonder if there's a timing-related edge case that we can maybe work around by not doing everything in `viewDidLoad`. — Oh, I have one more idea! A series of `isActive = true` calls is not good; instead, you should compile all your constraints into an array and call `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` on the array. This keeps the layout engine from going insane. :)

Comment: Ok so I have tried using `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` and setting the arranged subviews still seeing no change. Ngl havent had to use SO for a good while this ones got me stumped. Maybe this is an issue with the simulator... hard to tell.

Comment: If you're using Xcode 13 you may want to try an earlier version

Comment: @Rob I am in fact using xcode 12. Perhaps I should actually update to 13 and see if anything changes. Will keep updated

Comment: Also test with different simulators because some simulators, such as the mini, are so buggy they shouldn't be used.